# Missing ID Keys in AN Tab

Tags: animation, node-editor

I'm missing ID keys properties.. Can I show them from somewhere?

When I add new key no property bar appears.. just the names..

Image on the left shows How "ID Keys" tab looks in my current scene.
On the right - How "ID Keys" look in New scene. There is a property bar for each default and my newly created ID key.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I've got it.. simply select 1 object (not a group) and the properties of the IDs will appear